# Windows-7 changes input language automatically

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, input-language

I have encountered very strange problem recently. Windows changes input language on its own. I set it, for example, English, and then when I type (either on word, browser, or notepad, or anything) it switches the input language to Russian. This happens for certain letter combinations as far as I have noticed.

What could be the problem? At the moment I am installing anti-malware, hoping that it may find something. I have tried many things, many suggestions, that have been posted on forums, but none helped.

I would really appreciate your help in this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/how-can-i-make-the-keyboard-layout-selection-apply/056964db-e75c-4399-9a1d-686f33264598

Jérôme Pouiller's post in this link above, solved my problem.. 
it seems this is a bug.. so, only solution is to install third-party applications such as keyla, kbswitch..